# Ошибка: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript

Не пойму, почему выбивает ошибку?
Скобки все на месте.

```js
    var someObj={
      name:"Sergey",
      age:25,
      
      info:function(){
       console.log("Имя:"this.name+" возраст:"this.age);
      }
     };
    someObj.info();
```

Comment: Чего вы ожидаете от этого выражения `"Имя:"this.name+" возраст:"this.age`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропустил оператор `+` в двух местах

```js
var someObj = {
  name: "Sergey",
  age: 25,

  info: function() {
    console.log("Имя:" + this.name + " возраст:" + this.age);
  }
};
someObj.info();
```

Comment: Любопытно, кому мой ответ не понравился?)))

Comment: точно ,спасибо большое !

Comment: Для опечаток есть специальная причина для закрытия

Comment: @Grundy, я в курсе...  Но ответить на вопрос то можно?

Comment: @Air, нет, так как проблема заключается в опечатке. вопрос следовало закрыть и в комментариях просто показать место

Comment: Ок....   Закрыл бы его без голосования, у тебя же есть право на это...?    Или это когда дубликат?